# How to update the app on the app store if the project name is changed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an app available at the app store and is running fine.
I have changed the app's project name from app1.xcodeproj to app2.xcodeproj.
Is it possible to submit app2.xcodeproj as the update for app1.xcodeproj.
I am done with the testing but now I am wondering if its possible to send it as an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the Xcode project makes no difference.  The only thing that has to be consistent when updating an app on Apple's App Store is the bundle identifier which is set in the info.plist file.

Comment: thanks. Its a great relief for me :) else i would have had to start the QA process again.